# Google Data Studio: calculate new field by couning existing one with 'cause' method

Tags: looker-studio

I've got a numeric field called `kids`. Values in this field range from 0 to 5.  I want also to add a new calculated field called `families`. When number of kids would be higher then 0 value for family on the same row should be 1, otherwise 0. So I want to do that with `CASE` statement like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN kids != 0 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

But this formula gives me only 1 or 0 for whole field instead of counting and summing values for each row separetly. I tried also do something like this:

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN kids != 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

But with the error:

> *Re-aggreagting metrics are not supported*

How can I count that properly?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score -1):

Due to the way fields are aggregated this is tricky. Google Data Studio is running your `CASE` statement on rows of data after they've been aggregated, rather than each individual family.

You may be able to achieve what you're after by also using a `COUNT_DISTINCT` function, or with a filter instead.